# Use Trigger to Change Date/Text in a Style Trigger for WPF DatePicker Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In the database I'm devoloping against, null-values for dates are stored either as  or '1/1/1 12:00 am'. I would like the datepicker, to display the "Please select Date" message, if the SelectedDate is bound to the value '1/1/1 12:00 am'.

So tried this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="SelectedDate" Value="01.01.0001"> 
<!--Please note, the app runs on a computer with German Timeformat, but I tried 01/01/01 12:00 am as well-->
            <Setter Property="SelectedDate" Value="null" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I aslo tried this

```
 <Setter Property="Text" Value="Please select date" />
```

However, none if these are working. How would I get this to work? I thik one problem is to pass the value of the trigger in the correct format, i.e. DateTime Dataype.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in one of two ways:

**Option 1**

Cleanse the data as it comes into the application, setting `DateTime` values to `null` where they are '1/1/1 12:00 am'.

**Option 2**

Use a condition in the `get` part of the property you are binding to so that the value is read by the `DatePicker` as `null`, e.g.:

```
private DateTime? _selectedDate;
public DateTime? SelectedDate
{
    get { return _selectedDate == DateTime.Parse("01.01.0001") ? null : _selectedDate; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedDate != value)
        {
            _selectedDate = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```